# change the color of tab text and the underline in materialize framework

Tags: css, materialize

The default color of materialize tabs are pinkish. Also the underline for the active tab. I want to customize that and add some styles. How do I do that?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Images:
 [Active tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQQZi.png) and 
 [Tab2 on hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbDG2.png)

Code changes in CSS for the effects in above 2 images :

```
        .tabs .tab a{
            color:#000;
        } /*Black color to the text*/

        .tabs .tab a:hover {
            background-color:#eee;
            color:#000;
        } /*Text color on hover*/

        .tabs .tab a.active {
            background-color:#888;
            color:#000;
        } /*Background and text color when a tab is active*/

        .tabs .indicator {
            background-color:#000;
        } /*Color of underline*/
```

Comment: Hope this helps ppl looking for the same question :)

Comment: add !important to this part of the CSS "  .tabs .tab a.active", otherwise it will be reset to the default every time you change tabs, ie the javascript will reset it.

Answer (score 11):

The best way to add custom CSS to Materialize 1.0.0 default tabs is the following:

```
.tabs .tab a {
  color: rgba(38, 166, 154, 0.7);
  /*Custom Text Color*/
}

.tabs .tab a:hover {
  color:#26a69a;
  /*Custom Color On Hover*/
}

.tabs .tab a:focus.active {
  color:#26a69a;
  /*Custom Text Color While Active*/
  background-color: rgba(38, 166, 154, 0.2);
  /*Custom Background Color While Active*/
}

.tabs .indicator {
  background-color:#26a69a;
  /*Custom Color Of Indicator*/
}
```

*If you want to keep the default styling of the framework, use the RGBA values as they are in the example.

Comment: Make sure to add !important to the "custom background color while active" part of the CSS: otherwise it will be overridden when the javascript changes tabs.

Answer (score -1):

For the underline color add `<div class="indicator orange" style="z-index:1"></div>` right before the `</ul>`, and for the text color use this `<li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test1" class="teal-text">Test 1</a></li>`


eg:

```
<ul class="tabs transparent" materialize="tabs">
  <li class="tab col s3">
    <a href="#test1" class="teal-text">Test 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab col s3">
    <a href="#test2" class="teal-text">Test 2</a>
  </li>
  <div class="indicator teal" style="z-index:1"></div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

Its very easy to apply predefined classes in materialize.

Just Refer Page : http://materializecss.com/color.html

Here I have applied classes teal lighten-2 but there are various combination of classed from which you can choose from. Additionally you can write your own custom class and apply that too.

**HTML :**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <ul class="tabs teal lighten-2">
      <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
      <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test2">Test 2</a></li>
      <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test3">Test 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="test1" class="col s12">Test 1</div>
  <div id="test2" class="col s12">Test 2</div>
  <div id="test3" class="col s12">Test 3</div>
  <div id="test4" class="col s12">Test 4</div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/doska9qe/

Comment: @KruthikaCS : Happy to help ! :)

Comment: @Adarsh : What exactly, have you checked the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/doska9qe/ ?

Comment: @Adarsh : You need to include css and js as well on page.

Comment: I'm already using Tabs but this method didn't work for me. It's making everything teal. I just want fonts and the underline.

Comment: @Adarsh : You have not configured your code man. Take proper reference from JSFiddle. You should be able to get it.

Comment: @Adarsh, please check my answer above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41406867/7253565

It covers all most everything related to materialize tabs
I've added pictures for reference too.

Comment: The question is not about tabs background color, it's about underline color and text color. CSS is required to change such color.